# NoSuchFileException even though there is? Java (trying to add file on startup windows)

Tags: java, file, exception

```
        String hi = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String noes = "%USERPROFILE%\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\";
        String sex = "/bin/s";
        Path FROM = Paths.get(hi, sex);
        Path TO = Paths.get(noes, "s");
        System.out.println(TO);
        try {
            Files.copy(FROM, TO);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Debug:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\s
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Sand N\workspace\miner\bin\s -> %USERPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\s
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(WindowsFileCopy.java:205)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:278)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1225)
    at miner.mine.main(mine.java:18)
```

Would appreciate all help, thanks so much stackoverflower's!

I'm pretty confused to be honest, not such what's wrong unfortunately.

I know for a fact the startup folder path is correct, but I'm not sure if Java likes certain keys like %, /, etc.

Comment: My guess is that the environment property `%USERPROFILE%` is not being resolved. Use `System.getProperty("user.home")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of accessing windows environment path directly, try with `System.getenv("USERPROFILE")` to get the directory of user profile and then build the path.

```
 String noes =  System.getenv("USERPROFILE") + "\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\";
```

Comment: Thank you sir, appreciated!

Comment: No need to call me a sir. I am a learner too. And make sure to check the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page to know how to use this site. Welcome to stackoverflow.